# How to format postgres result in the same way that "TABLE name;" does?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pretty-print

I am using Postgres in a nodejs program, and I want to have functions that print the output to the terminal.

When you run the command "TABLE table_name;" in the terminal, you get a nice looking table with space for all characters in all columns [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9MyN.png)

When I run this same query, and try to display it like this:

```
console.log(pool.query("TABLE table_name")
```

I get [something that looks way worse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhQ1O.png). Is there some plugin I can get to make it look as good as the first image? Note: It would be displaying in the windows command prompt if that changes anything.

I tried doing my own with some character counting and inserting "\t|\t" into strings, however if the database gets quite large, running multiple times through the data would take  too long.

Comment: You need to write your own code for that. Nothing in the JDBC driver or standard Java libraries will do that.

Answer (score 1):

console.table() worked perfectly for me.